# Saving data in a One To Many Relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

My Core data Model Looks like this.

[image]

Below function saves attendance data as part of an employee(should be available in credentials table).

```
func addOrUpdateAttendanceReport(data: [AttendanceSummaryInfoDTO]){

    let doesEmpExist = validateEmpCredentials(ofThe: EmpCredentialsDTO(empMailId: currentActiveEmpId, empPassword: ""))

    if doesEmpExist{
        let emp = getCurrentEmpRecord(ofTheEmployee: currentActiveEmpId)

        var attendanceSummarySet = [Attendance]()
        for info in data
        {
            let attendanceInfo = Attendance(context: dbContext)
            attendanceInfo.status = info.leaveType
            attendanceInfo.reptDate = info.reptDate

            attendanceSummarySet.append(attendanceInfo)
        }
        emp.attendanceReport = NSSet(array: attendanceSummarySet)

        do{
            try dbContext.save()

        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")  // something bad happened, handle this situation appropriately

        }

    }
    else{
        print("Unable to save attendance summary info because, there is no employee exist with current id in local database ")
    }
}
```

Data saved successfully, but when i view the records using simMagnifier tool, a null record is saved in Credentials table along with the actual record.

When i run it again, one more null record is saved in credentials table along with records saved in Attendance table with parent as null.

I can't able to figure out route cause of this problem. My working environment is Xcode 8.3.1,iOS 10.3.1 and swift 3.

Additional code:

```
func getCurrentEmpRecord(ofTheEmployee id: String) -> Credentials {

let emp = Credentials(context: dbContext)
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Credentials> = Credentials.fetchRequest()

fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "empId == %@", id)

do {
    let searchResults = try dbContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    if searchResults.count > 0 {
        for record in searchResults {
            return record
        }
        return emp
    } else {
        return emp
    }
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error)")
    return emp
}
}
```

Comment: Try to replace `emp.attendanceReport = NSSet(array: attendanceSummarySet)` with `emp.addToAttendenceReport(NSSet(array: attendanceSummarySet))`

Comment: It is throwing error as, **Value of type 'Credentials' has no member 'addToaddToAttendenceReport'**. I am using CodeGen property of the entity as Class Defination.

Comment: Why `addToaddToAttendenceReport` (2 x addTo)?

Comment: sorry that is single addTo Its my typing mistake.

Comment: emp.addToAttendenceReport(NSSet(array: attendanceSummarySet)) i used exactly like this then Xcode throwing me with the following error **Value of type 'Credentials' has no member 'addToAttendenceReport'**.

Comment: Typo on my side also: `addToAttendenceReport` must be `addToAttendanceReport` (a not e).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142585/discussion-between-krishnarjun-banoth-and-shallowthought).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an empty `Credentials` every time you are calling `getCurrentEmpRecord()` and thus get an additional, empty entry in CoreData, if a `Credentials` with the given `id` exists.

Create it only if it does not exist:

```
func getCurrentEmpRecord(ofTheEmployee id: String) -> Credentials {
    //let emp = Credentials(context: dbContext) // do not create emp here ...
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Credentials> = Credentials.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "empId == %@", id)

    do {
        let searchResults = try dbContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        if searchResults.count > 0 {
            return searchResults.first!
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }

    let emp = Credentials(context: dbContext) // ... but only if you need to create it
    return emp
}
```

---

Update:

How I understand the name of the methode ("getCurrentEmpRecord"), you do not want to create an empty `Credential` at all, not even if no `emp` with the given `id` exists.

```
func getCurrentEmpRecord(ofTheEmployee id: String) -> Credentials? {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Credentials> = Credentials.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "empId == %@", id)

    do {
        let searchResults = try dbContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        if searchResults.count > 0 {
            return searchResults.first!
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Xcode throwing me an error as missing return type, since catch block does not returns anything, this is the reason to create empty Credentials in my previous code.

Comment: Can not test in the moment, sorry. Updated answer with hopefully working version. You must not create a `Credentials` in the database if you do not want to persist it in your DB.

Comment: Thank u so much shallowThought u saved my day.